# Libref error in WRDS Cloud SAS environment

Tags: sas, wrds-compusat

I use WRDS server via the WRDS Cloud using SAS. Trying the code below, I received the error (below the code). How can I fix it.

```
* Download Moody's annual accounting data;
proc sql;
  create table moody as
  select gvkey, datadate, mval
  from mdy.annlt;
quit;
```

**ERROR: Libref MDY is not assigned.**
**NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of
statements.**

This code does not work to solve the error:

- Set up libraries for WRDS access;

libname moody wrds.mdy;

Comment: What about `libname mdy wrds.mdy`? You are referring to libref `mdy` but assign a libname `moody`.

Comment: it also gives error:  libname mdy wrds.mdy;
 ERROR: Libref in LIBNAME statement must be followed either by quoted string or 
        engine name or semicolon; "wrds.mdy" found.
 ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: Check out the documentation of [`libname`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/da/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsglobal/n1nk65k2vsfmxfn1wu17fntzszbp.htm). You have to specify `wrds` as a path, e.g. something like this: `libname wdy "/wrds/<path>";`. Possibly, but this is a pure guess, your path is `/wrds/wdy` ..